# Why might OpenFileDialog::ShowDialog() take ~5 seconds to return after clicking the 'OK' button?

Tags: winforms, openfiledialog

I have the following code to prompt a user for a file to open:

```
System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog fd;
fd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
fd.RestoreDirectory = true;
if (fd.ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
{
    m_lblProgress->Text = "Opening file";                
}
```

For some reason, after I click the OK button on the dialog, it takes ~5 seconds before the text on the GUI is updated and it's unresponsive until that happens.

Why might that be and how can I avoid it?

**Edit - The plot thickens..**

This delay only appears when the `OpenFileDialog` is launched from a `System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem::Click` event.

Changing a label's text instead of launching the `OpenFileDialog` doesn't incur any delay at all so what's special about closing the `OpenFileDialog` window?

Comment: OpenFileDialog loads all the shell extensions into your process.  Programmers tend to use a lot of them, plenty of flaky ones around.  They can keep the debugger pretty busy as well.  Have a look-see in the Output window, with some luck you'll see a signal when you have the unmanaged debugging engine enabled.  Use SysInternals AutoRuns to disable them one by one until you find the troublemaker.

Comment: I could understand that making the file dialog take longer to appear, but would it really explain it taking longer to disappear? I will certainly give your suggestion a shot..